# Flag email for follow-up in compose field

Tags: office-365, outlook-365

In the outlook for client application, I can flag an email for follow-up directly from the compose window (see screenshot below). Is there a way to do this in Outlook 365?

The only way I can find is to send the email, go to my "sent" folder and flag it there, which is really annoying.

[image]